# WinRM - the specified credentials were rejected by the server

Tags: python, kerberos, winrm

I am unable to get WinRM session in a python script.

### Environment

```
ad-dns.test.com    - Windows 2012 AD and DNS Server
box88.test.com     - CentOS 7.2 : Kerberos, Python (Not joined to domain)
box62.test.com     - Windows 2012 R2 Standard (Joined to domain)
box63.test.com     - Windows 10 (Joined to domain)
```

---

### Configurations

I have enabled WinRM on Windows 10 and 2012 server through [ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1) PowerShell script. These are the WinRM configurations.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts = *
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 10
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 25
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 1024
        MaxShellsPerUser = 30
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

I have prepared CentOS box as below

```
# yum -y install python-pip python-devel krb5-devel krb5-libs krb5-workstation
# pip install --upgrade pip
# pip install  "pywinrm>=0.1.1" kerberos pykerberos requests-kerberos isodate xmltodict

# cat /etc/krb5.conf
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = TEST.COM

[realms]
 TEST.COM = {
  kdc = ad-dns.test.com
  admin_server   = ad-dns.test.com
  kpasswd_server = ad-dns.test.com
  default_domain = test.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 .test.com = TEST.COM
 test.com = TEST.COM
#

# kinit vkumar@TEST.COM
Password for vkumar@TEST.COM:
# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: vkumar@TEST.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2016-06-30T02:15:20  2016-06-30T12:15:20  krbtgt/TEST.COM@TEST.COM
    renew until 2016-07-01T02:15:16
#
```

### Problem

Until now, everything appears smooth. The problem occurs when I try to use this kerberos ticket to authenticate the Windows servers using the below script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import winrm

s = winrm.Session('box63.test.com', auth=('vkumar@TEST.COM', 'IamUsingKerbTicket'), transport='kerberos')
r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
print r.status_code
print r.std_out
print r.std_err


# ./winrm_ipconfig.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./winrm_ipconfig.py", line 6, in <module>
    r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/__init__.py", line 37, in run_cmd
    shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 132, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 207, in send_message
    return self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 179, in send_message
    raise InvalidCredentialsError("the specified credentials were rejected by the server")
winrm.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server
#
```

Not sure, why I see this error while `Event Logs` on Windows server show success. Apparently, I see three `Logon` and `Logoff` occurring at the same time. 
[image: Windows_Event_Logs]

Not sure what I am missing here. Firewall is stopped/disabled on both CentOS & Windows machines and times are also in sync.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solved it finally, it was a permission issue and not invalid credentials as pointed out in logs. There are two solutions to this issue

1. Add the domain user to the `Domain Admins` Group
2. Execute `winrm configSDDL default` on the Windows server and check `Read` and `Execute` permissons like below

[image: Windows_Server]

Comment: what if I don't have access to changing group/username? all I have the only `SOME_GROUP\Administrator` user. Can I user this user to execute?

Comment: Hi vikas027 , why is the domain admin group required? I'm facing the same issue, going to have a problem getting on that group, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Basic authentication i.e. Local usernames , then you need to set it as True using the following commands in Powershell (As admin)

```
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
```

Comment: Doesn't Basic expose a security issue by not using Kerberos to authenticate?